# Insertar datos de un checkbox a un select

Tags: php

como podria hacer que mi checkbox al presionar cualqueira vaya insertando datos que estan en mi base de datos a un select, si en caso presiona mas checkbox que se vaya listando en un solo select los datos de la base de datos,

```
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="" value="">dato1</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="" value=""> dato2</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""> dato3</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="checkbox"  name="" value="">dato4 </td></tr>
         </table>
   
               <select name="" id="" >
                    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Vas a necesitar Ajax, o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript, para ir a buscar los datos al servidor cada vez que haya una acción en el cliente (en este caso la selección de un checkbox). Otra posibilidad sería tener los datos precargados e irlos mostrando, pero esto no es óptimo si hablamos de muchos datos, porque el renderizado de la página podría ser lento. Sea como sea, debes decidir qué herramienta usar: Ajax, Fetch, otra ... y en base a eso podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: no se puede usar solo php?

Comment: Sí, pero sería programar *a la antigua*, teniendo, cada vez que quieras actualizar algo (cada checkbox seleccionado o deseleccionado por ejemplo) volver a recargar la página y renderizarla. Hoy día ya no se programa de ese modo. Ajax o Fetch son herramientas que aprendes a usarlas en un día.

Comment: eso que quieres hacer, no se hace ... XD